# Select if another select returns rows

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im trying to make a select to make cooking recipe select within the items you have.

i have a table named **ingredientsOwn** with the following structure:

```
idType (int) amount (int)
```

Another table named **recipes** with this structure:

```
idRecipe (int) name (varchar)
```

And another table named **recipeIngredients**

```
idRecipe (int) idType (int) amount (int)
```

I would like to show the recipes you can do with the elements you have, how could i perform this?

Im trying to implement it in only one query cause i really dont know how to go throw and array on node js.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go around this is, try to compute for each recipe, the number of ingredients you need, and join that with the number of ingredients own, and if the two numbers match, you have a candidate recipe.

So, to get the number of ingredients a recipe needs you'll have to do something like (this is more like a sql server syntax, so please try to focus in the concepts, and not the syntax):

```
select idRecipe, count(*) as neededIngredientsCount
from recipeIngredients
group by idRecipe
```

To get the number of available ingredients for each receipe, you have to join your ingredientsOwn with recipeIngredients, to be able to tell how many matching ingredients you have for each recipe.

```
select ingredientsOwn.idRecipe, count(*) as matchingIngredientsCount
from ingredientsOwn inner join recipeIngredients
on ingredientsOwn.idType = recipeIngredients.idType
where ingredientsOwn.amount >= recipeIngredients.amount
group by ingredientsOwn.idRecipe
```

Now you join the previous 2 queries to get the idRecieps that you have enough ingredients for, and join them with the recipes table to get the recipe name.

```
select r.idRecipe, r.name from
((select idRecipe, count(*) as neededIngredientsCount
from recipeIngredients
group by idRecipe) as in
inner join
(select ingredientsOwn.idRecipe, count(*) as matchingIngredientsCount
from ingredientsOwn inner join recipeIngredients
on ingredientsOwn.idType = recipeIngredients.idType
where ingredientsOwn.amount >= recipeIngredients.amount
group by ingredientsOwn.idRecipe) as io
on in.idRecipe = io.idRecipe
    and in.neededIngredientsCount = io.matchingIngredientsCount
inner join
(select * from recipes) as r
on r.idRecipe = in.idRecipe)
```

Hope this helps, and sorry for not being able to provide valid mysql syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM recipes INNER JOIN (
    select idRecipe from recipeIngredients
    WHERE recipeIngredients.idType IN (
        SELECT ingredientsOwn.idType from ingredientsOwn
    )
) as a ON a.idRecipe = recipes.idRecipe
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.